# Using redux connect on React.PureComponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found in React documentation that you can use PureComponent instead of Component, which implements shallow props comparison and boost component performance.

I connect my components to redux using connect which already implements shallow props comparison in connected components.

Did you know there is other benefits than shallow comparison when using PureComponent instead of Component with react-redux?

Comment: To be honest I thought shallow props comparison was default in react, also for the regular react components. My guess would be that PureComponent simply forces you to apply best practices when mutating your props or state.

Comment: Shallow comparison is *not* the default. The default is "return true" https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate